# Using formula as a condition in do while loop

Tags: vba, loops, while-loop

I have a column with Time values:

```
05:13:32
05:13:32
05:13:32
05:13:32
05:13:33
05:13:33
05:13:34
05:13:34
05:13:35
05:13:35
05:13:36
05:13:36
05:13:36
05:13:37
05:13:37
05:13:38
05:13:38
05:13:39
05:13:39
```

These Values are in Column C.

Now: the first point is the point where I begin to look for the next Value which is 2 seconds more than the first Value, it means I will find 05:13:34.

I wrote this code, but it doesnt work because `Find` function (What:=) doesn't accept a varible I declared as `x= Activecell.Value + "00:00:2"`

```
Sub sekundenfinder2()
    Dim sekundo2 As Range
    Dim x as Integer 
    Range("C153").Select  
    ' //// Here is the Point where I begin to go the colomn down and look for the next value 

    Selection.Activate
    Set sekundo2 = Range("C:C").Find(What:="x", After:=ActiveCell)
    sekundo2.Select
End Sub
```

The second question:

`Activecell.Value` gives a value 0,21......., which means that Excel turns the value from time to a number, but I want to keep the time in this format "00:00:00". I tried to change format to Time, and it still changed it to a number.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `DateAdd` to add times
2. when you use `x` inside quotes, it doesn't remain a variable but chnages to a string.
3. Declare `x` as `Date` and not `Integer`

Is this what you are trying? I am assuming that the data is from `C1` onwards and `C1` has `05:13:32`

```
Sub sekundenfinder2()
    Dim sekundo2 As Range
    Dim x As Date

    x = DateAdd("s", 2, Range("C1").Value)

    Set sekundo2 = Range("C:C").Find(What:=x)

    If Not sekundo2 Is Nothing Then sekundo2.Select
End Sub
```

[image]